# RegEx capture part of text

Tags: regex

Could you help me, please!
I have a string like this:

`C:\Temp dir\Some one else\File name.ext`

I need to capture `File name.ext`
But I can't understand how do it by regex.

When I trying to create `regexp` I can't understand how to capture only last symbol `\` and a text between them and `.`

Answer (score 3):

Hmm.. the following RegEx should do it:

```
\\[^\\]*\.
```

Depending on your language and environment, further escaping may be required for the backslashes and/or other characters.

Comment: actually, this would capture `\File name.` when the OP wants `File name.ext`.

Comment: So put the `()` around the bit you want to capture... or just leave the initial `\\ ` off.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
[^\\]*\.\w+$
```

Use `$` to anchor to end.

Breakdown explanation of the regex:

```
[^\\]*   Match the file name. (Any characters other than a \)
\.       Match the '.'.
\w+      Match the extension.
$        Anchor to end.
```

Comment: What if the file doesn't have an extension?

Comment: @VasiliSyrakis Then it will not be captured. The question specifically mentioned wanting to capture files with extensions.

Comment: @Doorknob of Snow Could you explain me please: how I managed to select the part what I need, for example: between 4th and 7th \ or between 4th \ and 8th . Thank you!

Comment: @huxahetu I'm not sure I understand your question... is this regex not working?

Comment: @DoorknobofSnow it is all OK, but I'm trying to understand the main principles. For example, if want to select: Some \text \with \ and. . many . WANT TO CAPTURE TEXT WITH NUMBERS 111 some \ another \ and .another. How I managed to capture: WANT TO CAPTURE TEXT WITH NUMBERS 111

Answer (score 1):

In response to comments on other questions, here is an alternative.

If you want to capture text between backslash 6 and 7 you can do the following:

```
(?:[^\\]*\\){6}([^\\]*)
```

Explanation:

```
(?: ){6}   A non-capturing group repeated 6 times
[^\\]*     Any number of characters other than backslash
\\.        Followed by backslash
([^\\]*)   capture all non backslash characters that follow
```

You can see this at work (with better explanation) at http://regex101.com/r/fP2cL7

If you want a match between backslash 4 and 7, it would be

```
    (?:[^\\]*\\){4}((?:[^\\]*\\){2}[^\\]*)
```

As above but "don't do anything with the first four backslashes", then capture "no backslash followed by backslash twice, followed by no backslash one more time". Which captures everything from backslash 4 to backslash 7 (without including the slashes at the end)

Answer (score 0):

### Using Powershell

`(gci $filepath).Name`

---

### Using Regex

`(?!.*\\).*`

This will match everything after the last slash `\`